# Update TextArea value based on number of listbox selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox, textarea

If I have a listbox and a textarea:

```
<textarea id="MyTextArea"></textarea>

<select id="SelectList" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do is... if there are more than `0` selected options.. then append the text `There are selections` to the textarea.

If the user deselects the options to the point where there are `0` selected options then erase that string from the textarea, but keep whatever else the user typed in that textarea.

Here is what I have:

```
$("#SelectList").change(function(){
    var count = $("#SelectList> option:selected").length;
    var string = "There are selections.";
    var txtVal = $("#MyTextArea").val();

    if (count > 0 && txtVal.indexOf(string) == -1) {
        $("#MyTextArea").append(string);
    }
    else if (count > 0 && txtVal.indexOf(string) != -1) {
    }
    else if (count === 0 && txtVal.indexOf(string) != -1) {
        var indexOfString = $("#MyTextArea").value.indexOf(string);
        $("#MyTextArea").value.substring(0, indexOfString - 1);
    }
});
```

This works for adding the string only once.  But when I deselect all of the options so that there are `0` selections.. I get this:

> Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference

On this line: `var indexOfString = $("#MyTextArea").value.indexOf(string);`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
var indexOfString = $("#MyTextArea").val().indexOf(string);
```

Because `$("#MyTextArea")` is a jQuery element

Answer (score 2):

The `.value` is a pure js method you can't call it on jQuery object `$("#MyTextArea")` instead you could use `val()`, like :

```
$("#MyTextArea").val().indexOf(string);
```

And since you've already stored the value on variable `txtVal` you could just call it like :

```
$("#SelectList").change(function(){
    ...
    else if (count === 0 && txtVal.indexOf(string) != -1) {
        var indexOfString = txtVal.indexOf(string);
        txtVal.substring(0, indexOfString - 1);
    } 
});
```

**NOTE :** You shouldn't use `append()` method on `textarea` instead use `.val()` :

```
$("#MyTextArea").val(txtVal + string);
```

Instead of :

```
$("#MyTextArea").append(string);
```

Hope this helps.